# How to quit default values in html inputs

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an html form that :
[looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It252.png)

And I want that those values doesn't appear like these, just blank.

How can I do it?

The code in fact is here: [github](https://github.com/munozloisivan/mean-app/tree/master/src/app/book-create)

Answer (score 0):

Blank input as you want... please run and see

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Add New Book</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form (ngSubmit)="saveBook()" #bookForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">ISBN</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="book.isbn" name="isbn" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="book.title" name="title" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Author</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="idA"  name="author" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="book.author"  name="author" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Publisher</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="book.publisher" name="publisher" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="book.price" name="price" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!bookForm.form.valid">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  
</div>
```